# Django Save Related Models with FormView CBV

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='articles')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="article/")
    start_page = models.IntegerField()
    end_page = models.IntegerField()

class Author(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='authors')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    affiliate = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Abstract(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='abstracts')
    content = models.TextField()
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
         unique_together = ('article', 'is_primary')

class Keyword(models.Model):
    abstract = models.ForeignKey(Abstract, related_name='keywords')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So the relations like:

- Each article may have multiple author.
- Each article have only 2 abstract, primary and optional depending on is_primary field condition.
- Each abstract may have multiple keywords.

I've create a one form that contains all the fields that necessary by above classes. Which means that I need to populate all models with one `<form>` tag.

Here is my start point for ModelForm.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    issue = ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['issue', 'title', 'file', 'start_page', 'end_page']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['issue'].queryset = Issue.objects.filter(volume__journal__user=user)
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['rows'] = 3
        self.fields['file'].widget.attrs['accept'] = "application/pdf"
        self.fields['start_page'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = _("Start Page")
        self.fields['end_page'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = _("End Page")
        # Lets add form-control css class into the each field
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Since issue field of Article model is FK to the another model. I've used queryset definition at **init** of.

Here is the CBV that I've used for article form.

```
class ArticleUploadView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
template_name = "article/upload_article.html"
form_class = ArticleForm
success_url = reverse_lazy("journal_manage")
success_message = "Yeeey!"

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ArticleUploadView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(ArticleUploadView, self).form_valid(form)
```

So far, everything is working like a charm! To be honest, I'm very happy to be able to come so far.

But I don't know how to involve other models such as Authors, Abstract and Keywords. CreateView only supports one form_class but it seems that I have to create another forms for other models but I couldn't figure out how to continue ?

Somehow I need to save article first, then authors -which is FK to the article model. Then Abstracts and Keywords which is also FK to the abstract.

Comment: I am sure that you should override 'post' method of your view and create formset for each model. To be sincere, I wouldn't recommend using CreateView in this case at all.